# "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" onmousemove

Tags: javascript, html, cursor, undefined, onmousemove

So on my website, I want some text to follow my cursor. I use the following JS:

```
var balls = document.getElementsByClassName("text1");
  document.onmousemove = function(){
    var x = event.clientX * 100 / window.innerWidth + "%";
    var y = event.clientY * 100 / window.innerHeight + "%";

    for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
      balls[i].style.left = x;
      balls[i].style.top = y;
      balls[i].style.transform = "translate(-"+x+",-"+y+")";
    }
  };
```

but in chrome I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
> at HTMLDocument.document.onmousemove (script.js:7) document.onmousemove @ script.js:7

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Well, apparently `balls[0]` (or `balls[1]`) is undefined. I don't have context to see what `document.getElementsByClassName("text1");` is, but it is not returning an array as you seem to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are looping till "i==2" but you might have attached the "text1" class to only 1 element and that's why when the loop reached balls[1] then it threw the error of "*Cannot read property 'style' of undefined*".

So either decreases the loop maximum value or attaching the "text1" class to more elements.

Here is the working example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
  var balls = document.getElementsByClassName("text1");
  document.onmousemove = function() {
    var x = event.clientX * 100 / window.innerWidth + "%";
    var y = event.clientY * 100 / window.innerHeight + "%";
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      balls[i].style.left = x;
      balls[i].style.top = y;
      balls[i].style.transform = "translate(-" + x + ",-" + y + ")";
    }
  };
</script>

<body>
  <p class="text1">Hello</p>
  <p class="text1">World</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Good answer! Could you add option to run snippet?